# Application.cfc extending values into a child folder

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I am currently updating some of my Coldfusion applications, and I am looking for a good way to keep some of the structure in place.

Currently, its setup like this

> ```
> ApplicationRoot/Application.cfc (handles things like login, init etc..)
> ApplicationRoot/Admin (I want exact same var's as parent folder, but few extra checks to ensure the user has admin rights)
> ```

Currently, the setup works with an Application file in each directory (and it does work), but it gets messy by declaring everything like application/session scopes over again. Is there a better way?

Comment: Sean Corfield has a blog entry about extending your root Application.cfc. [Read about it here.](http://corfield.org/blog/index.cfm/do/blog.entry/entry/Extending_Your_Root_Applicationcfc)

Comment: Might also want to search the archives as there are several existing threads about [extending an Application.cfc](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[coldfusion]+extend+application.cfc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Application.cfc` in the admin subdir, extend the one in the parent dir, eg:

```
component extends="ApplicationProxy" {

    // eg: if you need to do something different in the local onApplicationStart:
    public void function onApplicactionStart(){
        super.onApplicationStart();
        // stuff that's different from the parent goes here
    }    

    // if there's nothing different for a given handler, then don't have one in here: the super one will still fire

    // otherwise override each handler in a similar fashion to the onApplicationStart above, with:
    // a) a call to its super equivalent
    // b) anything that needs overriding

}
```

In your base dir, add `ApplicationProxy.cfc`, thus:

```
component extends="Application" {

}
```

The reason for this is that a sub `Application.cfc` cannot have `extends="Application"`, because that seems like a circular reference.  However there's no better "qualified" way of identifying an Application.cfc in the base dir, so one needs a proxy.

Comment: I basically did this (used mapping rather then the ApplicationProxy, but the idea is the same)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this in your Application.cfc on RequestStart():

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="boolean" output="false" hint="I handle page requests." >
  <cfargument name="requestname" type="string" required="true" >

  <cfif FileExists(GetDirectoryFromPath(arguments.requestname) & '/admin.cfm')>
    <cfinclude template="#GetDirectoryFromPath(arguments.requestname)#/admin.cfm">
  </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Then, in each directory you want to have custom variables set up, put a admin.cfm file. In this admin.cfm file just put a bunch of  tags or however you want to set up your session and application variables.

Comment: Hah, I don't remember seeing this answer here 21 minutes ago. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also just put a check to see what directory the user is executing and then just have the extra code run. So, in your main application.cfc onRequestStart() for example, you can have say, "is the current request for the admin folder?" Ok, run function X which includes all your security functionality. You can even include this code as extra functions within your application.cfc if you like.

Alternatively, if you go with one of the other answers by doing the extends stuff, you'll want to put a super.function() call in each function where you want other code to run. For example with onRequest start, super.onRequestStart() at the beginning of your sub-Application.cfc onRequestStart() to call the parent stuff before the child fires off.

I personally prefer the first method as it keeps it tidy when you truly do have just one application.

Comment: Whilst you COULD do this, it's kinda working against the way it's intended to be done with the application framework (ie: Application.cfc).  Cheers for the clarification of the super stuff. I forgot to mention that in my answer, and have now augmented it to include an example.